# python, telegram bot, aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, бот

У меня есть telegram бот. В боте есть мини регистрация, которая реализована на машине состояний. Но есть нюанс после некоторых шагов регистрации машина состояний ждет фото, а иногда люди отвлекаются от регистрации и пытаются отправить команду, в ответ ничего, отправляют ещё раз опять ничего, люди думают, что бот завис, но бот все ещё ждёт фото. Как можно реализовать возможность обработки конкретных команд, например, */start* во время ожидания фото.

```
    @dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state=ProfilStatesGroup.photo)
async def id(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['photo'] = message.photo[0].file_id
    await message.answer('''Мой текст''', parse_mode='HTML')
    await bot.send_photo(id, photo=data['photo'], caption=f'''Мой текст''')
await state.finish()
```

> В данном пример машина ждёт фото, и если отправить что-то другое бот будет молчать, как допустим не игнорировать команду */start* и несколько других команд бота в таком случае, а обработать и ответить на них?

Comment: ну и напишите хендлер, который будет реагировать в текущем состоянии на все кроме фото - будет писать нечто: "Сейчас я жду фото, ничего кроме фото"

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можете попробовать добавить отмену состояний в свою команду `/start`:

```
@dp.message_handler(state='*', commands='start')
async def cancel_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.finish()
    ...  # тут ваш остальной код для команды start
```

таким образом `/start` должен срабатывать даже если бот находится в каком то из состояний и ждет ответа от пользователя

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Lesha если вам понравился ответ, то можете нажать стрелочку вверх слева от него ))